# How to keep itemsControl items content from stretching to width of widest item

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to make the itemsControl items content (in this case a border) **not stretch** to fit the width of the widest item?

See here:

[image]

CURLIN is the widest item. RAGAIN and WALKUP are shorter, but stretch to CURLIN's width, regardless of any itemsPanel or itemTemplate I try. Can this be helped?

Code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CarbonCopyRecipients}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate >
               <Border ...... />
         </DataTemplate >
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Inside the `DataTemplate`, Place a `StackPanel` and add the Children Horizontally. This will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: ItemsControl.Width = 100 would stop ItemsControl from stretching :-) Just set fix width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since I guess I was right in my assumption of what you were after and of course am a glutton for points, here you go;

The children elements of your `StackPanel` will fill the available space set by the largest object it contains unless you tell them not to explicitly or already have a template set to do the same.

So `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` on the outermost container of your `ItemTemplate` (in this case the `Border`) will tell it to hug the side instead of stretching to fit the space available for it to potentially consume.

The not so nerdy wordy version: Tell the bugger to just take the space it needs. :)

Hope it helps.